# Currently installing Windows Azure Pack: Web Sites v2, but it is not present in my web installer 4.6, what would be the reason?

Tags: azure, hadoop, bigdata

I am currently installing Windows Azure Pack: Web Sites v2, but in my web installer it is not available what's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Its only available in **Windows Server 2012** and **Windows Server 2012 R2**.

Refer deployment hardware and software prerequisites at

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469325.aspx

Dharmendra